# Can semantics work independently apart from philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, truth, semantics, vacuous

"Colorless green ideas sleep furiously."

It implies grammar can work independently apart from semantics.

So I was thinking: "Can semantics work independently apart from philosophy."? And there's my theory.

I don't have any child.
But there's a sentence "my child is big".

> "All my children are goats" is a vacuous truth, when spoken by someone without children. Similarly, "None of my children is a goat" would also be a vacuous truth, when spoken by the same person.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

According to vacuous truth, it's vacuously true, so it's true (vacuously).

But, think about it. How can "my child is big" be true even if I don't have any child"? So some says it's false.

But in Japanese, there's a universally-used expression "雨が降らなかった“ (it's used when it didn't rain). It's translated into "rain didn't fall", not "it didn't rain" as in western language.

Somebody says "rain didn't fall" is true and somebody doesn't. But this expression still has meaning and works. It negates that rain fell.

So my judgement is that meaningful sentences don't depend on whether they are true or not but whether they have meanings or not.

Does a statement that is vacuously true but meaningless, meaningless?

So, what do you think? Do you think that semantics works independently from philosophy? Does it matter philosophically?

Comment: I don't know that there would be an independence from philosophy *per se*, here: see about the [various semantic theories of category mistakes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-mistakes/#SemaAppr), for example.

Comment: People who know nothing about philosophy talk and understand each other, so yes. And people who know just a bit of philosophy of language know the difference between material and [indicative conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicative_conditional). Vacuous truth is not recognized in natural languages, it is an artifact of the material conditional. That meaning is derivative from reference (truth values) is part of classical Fregian semantics. Its limitations are also well-known, as well as alternatives to it, see [SEP, Theories of Meaning](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is meaningless nonsense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> It implies grammar can work independently apart from semantics.

This is trivial. All speakers of a language know that it is always possible to speak meaningless but grammatical sentences.

This is also not surprising. A language has to allow speakers to express any idea whatsoever.

Observe that this is also true of logic. Coincidence?

> "All my children are goats" is a vacuous truth, when spoken by someone without children. Similarly, "None of my children is a goat" would also be a vacuous truth, when spoken by the same person.

The notion of vacuous truth is an absurdity. What we say is either meaningless, true or false. As noted by Peter Strawson in his 1950's critique of Bertrand Russell's theory of descriptions, a speaker cannot genuinely assert "The king of France is bald" if he believes there is no king. The sentence "All my children are married" asserted by someone known to be without children would not be taken to be true by the addressee, and even less ***vacuously true*** because there is no such notion in real life. It simply doesn't exist. Mathematical logic is certainly not human logic.

The notion of vacuous truth is a purely rhetorical device. It was introduced to deflect the objection to the theory that the horseshoe ¬α ∨ β is the only reasonable model of the conditional "If α, then β" and therefore of the implication α → β.

> But, think about it. How can "my child is big" be true even if I don't have any child"?

It cannot.

> So some says it's false.

Bertrand Russell notoriously argued that "The king of France is bald" is false if there is no king. This, too, is simply absurd. This is not how language works, and this is not even how mathematics works.

> Can semantics work independently apart from philosophy

Philosophy is too vague a notion to answer this question, but semantics is an empirical science or it is not a science. The really interesting question is of the relation between semantics and logic.

> But in Japanese, there's a universally-used expression "雨が降らなかった“ (it's used when it didn't rain). It's translated into "rain didn't fall", not "it didn't rain" as in western language.

You would have to explain what notion of rain that the Japanese exactly have. A translation is not a reliable indication of the possible subtleties of the semantics of the original expression. The Japanese perhaps think of rain as something more abstract than we do. Maybe they think of it like we think of fate or death.

And Google's translation is "It didn't rain". So, no problem...

> So my judgement is that meaningful sentences don't depend on whether they are true or not but whether they have meanings or not.

A sentence is meaningful if it has meaning? Well, yes, sure.

Only sentences which are meaningful to someone can possibly be argued to be true or false. If nobody understands the sentence, nobody is going to argue that it is true, let alone prove that it is.

Sentences are true or false depending on what they mean, so they have to mean something to be possibly true or false.

If a sentence is meaningful, then we will normally say that it is true if we think that what we think it means is true.

Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar does provide meaning,  and is not distinct from it. There are multiple types of semantics. Chomsky's sentence has lexical semantics because you know what each of the words mean. Sentential semantics is the meaning conveyed by the sentence. The sentence,  for instance,  is declarative and in the present tense.   The lexemes also have compositional morphemes. Colorless, for example,  has two morphemes. The spelling of the words also encode phonetic meaning. You can pronounce it.

What is important to understand is that a grammar has rules which encode meaning, and according to some linguists, like constructivists,  the very phrasal structure carries meaning independent of the particular words. Consider how inflections and conjugations convey number, tense, and aspect even if the words are themselves nonsensical.

Semantics is not just the meanigful use of diction. Everything from the phonemes, to the lexicon and clitics, to the morphology to segment, text, discourse markers, and the discourse itself can carry meaning,  sometimes without explicit encoding as in the case of implicature or the observance of Gricean maxims or the nature of the speech act.